# How to do add transition to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Full code: https://codepen.io/vvaciej/pen/abPdEBN

**CSS part**

```
html body main .sidebar-area {
  display: none;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #171717;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #171717;
}

html body main .active {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
closeButton.addEventListener('click', closingMenuByButton);

const menuButton = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

function showSidebar () {
  if (!dropdownArea.classList.contains('active')) {
    dropdownArea.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    dropdownArea.classList.remove('active');
  }
};

menuButton.addEventListener('click', showSidebar);

function hideSidebarByClickOutside(e) {
    if (dropdownArea.classList.contains('active') && !menuButton.contains(e.target) && !dropdownArea.contains(e.target)) {
        dropdownArea.classList.remove('active');
    }
};

bodyArea.addEventListener('click', hideSidebarByClickOutside);
```

Want to add simple animation of displaying dropdown.
I'm counting on your help.

Comment: if by transition you meant the transition of the opacity property of your element, you may just drop the `display:none` strategy and add `opacity: 0;` to the `.sidebar-area` css rule. Then add a new rule `.active{transition: opacity 2s ease-out; opacity: 1;}` so that that when the class will be added, the element will show up gradually. The code you shared was useless so if you mean to have a better answer please simplify the codepen and share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've made some CSS updates. Initially, I removed the 'display: none' code, and then I moved the sidebar to the left by -100%. When it has the 'active' class, I set it to move to the left at 0, and I added a smooth transition.

```js
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.fa-x');
const dropdownArea = document.querySelector('.sidebar-area');
const bodyArea = document.querySelector('body');

function closingMenuByButton () {
  dropdownArea.classList.remove('active');
};

closeButton.addEventListener('click', closingMenuByButton);

const menuButton = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

function showSidebar () {
  if (!dropdownArea.classList.contains('active')) {
    dropdownArea.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    dropdownArea.classList.remove('active');
  }
};

menuButton.addEventListener('click', showSidebar);

function hideSidebarByClickOutside(e) {
    if (dropdownArea.classList.contains('active') && !menuButton.contains(e.target) && !dropdownArea.contains(e.target)) {
        dropdownArea.classList.remove('active');
    }
};

bodyArea.addEventListener('click', hideSidebarByClickOutside);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
html body {
  height: 100%;
}
html body:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 100%, transparent), url("/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.2);
  z-index: -999;
  inset: 0;
}
html body main {
  width: 100%;
}
html body main .sidebar-area {
  /* display: none; */
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #171717;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #171717;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content div i {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgba(229, 68, 68, 0.8156862745);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(229, 68, 68, 0.8156862745);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 28px;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .sidebar-title {
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-column-gap: 50px;
       column-gap: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .sidebar-title .title {
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 28px;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .sidebar-title .title:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content div .sidebar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  color: #ddd;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content div .sidebar-menu li {
  padding-left: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content div .sidebar-menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.6823529412);
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content div .sidebar-menu .contact-li {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .social-links {
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 25px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .social-links i {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #ddd;
  color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
html body main .sidebar-area .sidebar-content .social-links i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
html body main .main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 25px;
}
html body main .active {
  display: block;
}
html body main .author {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
html body main .content {
  width: 100%;
}
html body main .content .fa-bars {
  font-size: 22px;
  float: right;
  margin: 30px;
  color: lightblue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border: 1.3px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
}
html body main .content .fa-bars:hover {
  border-color: grey;
  color: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
html body main .body-area {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 9999px) {
  .sidebar-menu li {
    padding: 22px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .fa-x {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar-menu li {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}/*# sourceMappingURL=sidebar.css.map */

.sidebar-area {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: .5s all ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.sidebar-area.active {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: .5s all ease;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b367f4fd12.js" cr  ossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Quicksand:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css">
  <title>Sidebar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="sidebar-area">
      <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sidebar-title">
          <div>
            <span class="title">Sidebar&nbsp;<span style="color: lightblue;">Project</span>   
          </div>
          <div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li class="contact-li">Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 
        <div class="social-links">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="author">Author: Maciek S.</span>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please spend few words saying how did you address the problem instead of just feeding the user with the ready solution for his own purpose. I know that people don't read ... but the answers are not aimed at who asked. He was waiting for a ready to paste solution... that's not stackoverflow. Plus you considered the transition to be a slide from the left... it wasn't obvious.. and that's a further reason to avoid feeding lazy users

Answer (score 0):

`transition` is a CSS rule, you follow it with a colon `:`. Then, you list what you want to `transition` (`width`, for example) and how long the transition should take, separated by comma `,`. Example:

```
transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
```

Proof-of-concept:

```js
function changeSize(what, amount) {
    document.querySelector(".playground").style[what] = amount + "px";
}
```

```css
.playground {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="playground"></div>
Width: <input type="numer" value="100" oninput="changeSize('width', this.value)">
Height: <input type="numer" value="100" oninput="changeSize('width', this.value)">
```

Your `transition` values lack the subject as of whose `transition` time are we speaking about.